# Can this Ayurvedic concoction reduce chances of swine flu?

Tags: alternative-medicine, natural-remedies, disease, medical-science

The Indian Government is [openly](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/jaipur/Sale-of-swine-flu-vaccines-goes-up/articleshow/46170461.cms) [distributing](http://udaipurtimes.com/kadha-distributed-huge-numbers-21-patients-swine-flu-return-home/) an Ayurvedic Kadha ( concoction) that claims to reduce the chances of contracting Swine Flu. They're doing this along with the sale of vaccines for Swine Flu.

This concoction has the following recipe:

#### Ingredients:

- 7 **Cardamoms** ( Elaichi)
- 7 **Cloves** ( Laung)
- 7 **Holy Basil** leaves ( Tulsi)
- 1 small piece of **Fresh Ginger** ( Adrak)
- 1/4 small spoon of **Turmeric Powder** ( Haldi)
- 1 medium sized piece of **Cinnamon** (Dal Chini)
- 1/4 small spoon of **Black Salt**

#### Directions:

1. Put all ingredients in 4 cups of water.
2. Boil this till 3 cups have evaporated and you have 1 cup remaining.
3. Strain this liquid and store it in a glass bottle.
4. Consume 2 spoons of this liquid for 3 days after your morning ablutions on an empty stomach.

A [few](http://www.ayurvedatreatments.co.in/ayurvedatreatments/index.php/indian-herb-tulsi-can-prevent-swine-flu) [blogs](http://zeenews.india.com/home/tulsi-can-help-keep-swine-flu-away-ayurvedic-experts_534519.html) also claim that Tulsi is supposed to have anti-flu properties.

Comment: Not sure about more esoteric ingredients, but at the very least, Cinnnamon and Ginger are both known to be helpful in prevention of URIs in general.